# Text sharing webapp that allows upload via FTP

Tags: gratis, web-apps, ftp

I am looking for a text sharing webapp with the following requirements:

- Allow me to upload a text file via FTP
- Free, advertisement OK
- Shared texts are public, private feature are OK but not especially needed

What I have tried, and why they don't fit:

- [GitHub Gist](http://gist.github.com): no FTP upload feature
- [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/): no FTP upload feature

Comment: Must it display the texts (if yes, how? any features? metadata?), or is it sufficient to offer the text files for download?

Comment: @unor it is not required but would be nice to be displayed